Reportes con subReportes dinamicos en Jasper
como estan? etoy trabajando con java 17 y jasper report. en el cual estoy tratando de poder realizar una logica dinamica para combinar mas de un subreport dependiendo el objeto en cuestion. ejemplo, tengo un objeto que tiene gestion = 'J' va a usar el subreport1, si tengo otro objeto distinta gestion deberia usar el subReport2.
Codigo Java:
private JRBeanCollectionDataSource crearDatosTablaObjetos(List<RepDetEmisionSujetoEntity> detalles,
    List<RepObjetoEmisionSujetoEntity> objetoEmision, Map<String,Object> parameters) {
        ArrayList<CuerpoObjetoDTO> listaObjetos = new ArrayList<CuerpoObjetoDTO>();
        BigDecimal importeTotalActualizado = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for (RepObjetoEmisionSujetoEntity objeto : objetoEmision) {
            CuerpoObjetoDTO cuerpoObjetoDTO = new CuerpoObjetoDTO();
            cuerpoObjetoDTO.setTitulo(armarLeyendaTitulo(objeto));
            -mas objetos-

            List<RepDetEmisionSujetoEntity> detallesFiltrados = detalles.stream()
            .filter(detalle -> objeto.getId().getRdeId().equals(detalle.getId().getRdeRdeId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

            boolean contieneGestionJ = detallesFiltrados.stream()
                    .anyMatch(detalle -> "J".equals(detalle.getGestion()));

            JasperReport subReporte = getSubJasperReport(contieneGestionJ);
            parameters.put("subReport", subReporte);

            ArrayList<DetalleObjetoDTO> listaDetalles = new ArrayList<DetalleObjetoDTO>();
            for (RepDetEmisionSujetoEntity detalle : detallesFiltrados) {
                DetalleObjetoDTO detalleObjetoDto = new DetalleObjetoDTO();
                detalleObjetoDto.setTitulo(armarLeyendaTitulo(objeto));
                -mas detalles-

                importeTotalActualizado = importeTotalActualizado.add(detalle.getImporteActDeuda());

                // Si es judicial
                if(detalle.getGestion().equals("J")) {
                    detalleObjetoDto.setMartillero(ponerTextoOrVacio(detalle.getMartillero()));
                    detalleObjetoDto.setProcurador(ponerTextoOrVacio(detalle.getProcurador()));
                }
                listaDetalles.add(detalleObjetoDto);
            }
            cuerpoObjetoDTO.setDetalleObjetoDTO(listaDetalles);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
                filePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reportes/reporte_consolidada_sub_report.jrxml")
                        .getAbsolutePath();
                filePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reportes/reporte_sub_report_no_consolidada.jrxml")
                        .getAbsolutePath();

y  codigo de jasper
<subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="169" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4245096d-a3ed-402e-8d48-5107ff6654d7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{detalleObjetoDTO})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>

